# How I can resolve a Praser error?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to add a class Where is in assembly in my references so I used

```
<%@ page title=" " language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true"  culture="auto" uiculture="auto" Inherits="App_Web_oscnz2mo._Default"meta:resourcekey="PageResource2" enableviewstatemac="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" %>
```

I have this error`Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'App_Web_oscnz2mo._Default'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it ended up being in

Inherits="App_Web_oscnz2mo._Default"

_Default should just be the name of the class you want to add. I'm not sure if your problem is the same but it took me a while to figure what was stopping me.